# Web.config Transforms add extra line returns where there are none

Tags: asp.net, web-config

When my Web.config transforms it is adding a new line before the end value tag in my ApplicationSettings.  This new line is showing up in the setting and causing an exception.  Example:

Web.config:

```
        <setting name="FilePath" serializeAs="String">
            <value>c:\path</value>
        </setting>
```

Web.Debug.config:

```
        <setting name="FilePath" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
            <value>c:\path</value>
        </setting>
```

Published Web.config:

```
        <setting name="FilePath" serializeAs="String">
            <value>c:\path
            </value>
        </setting>
```

The end value tag being on its own line is causing problems.  Does anyone know how to get it to stop doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be the same question as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300210

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem, which is fixed in VS 2010 SP1, apparently.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544183/web-config-transform-writes-extra-line-break-spaces-to-values-elements-under-applicationsettings-section#

Answer (score 0):

No idea, but you could trim the string before you use it in the application...