# Is it possible to turn off the canonical hostname URL Rewrite rule from the codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I was wondering it is possible to turn off the canonical hostname URL Rewrite rule from the URL Rewrite 2.0 IIS 7.5 Module.

I'm locally developing on a IIS 7.5. The setting of this URL Rewrite rule is set in the web.config.

This is how I deploy: I'm using Webdeploy to publish my web application. The new web.config transforms, which was introduced with VS 2010, is no option for me, because it is bugged: [VS 2010 configuration transformation produces unwanted white space during deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300210/vs-2010-configuration-transformation-produces-unwanted-white-space-during-deploym) and will not be fixed until the release of VS2010 SP1. I'm also not using web deployment projects anymore, because Webdeploy does not seem working with web deployment projects. As a result, I manually switch on the rewrite rule in the web.config before deploying.

If I now want to locally debug something, I manually need to turn off the rule.

Is there a solution like this pseudo-code?

```
if(Properties.Settings.TurnOffCanonicalHostNameWithLocalHost)
{
  URLRewriteModule["CanonicalHostName"].Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
```