# Web.Config transforms with new line symbol

Tags: asp.net, web-config, transform, web-config-transform

I use .settings file in my application and I need to override settings in web.config file sometimes.

So here is an example of setting overridden by web.config:

```
    <applicationSettings>
        <ADM.Web.Admin.ADMSettings>
            <setting name="ApplicationWebAddress" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost:8929</value>
            </setting>
        </ADM.Web.Admin.ADMSettings>
    </applicationSettings>
```

And I need to change this setting depending on if I publish to Dev or Live site
So I discribe Web.Debug.config like this:

```
        <setting name="ApplicationWebAddress" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
            <value>http://dev.site.com</value>
        </setting>
```

and Web.Release.config:

```
        <setting name="ApplicationWebAddress" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
            <value>http://live.site.com</value>
        </setting>
```

After publishing I found the following in Web.Config File:

```
        <setting name="ApplicationWebAddress" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://live.site.com
            </value>
        </setting>
```

As u can see there is a new line before .
My question is Why there is "new line" and what to do to change one setting value to another one?

Comment: I had the same problem and Trim() the value as a quick fix. But this is clearly not a good solution.

Comment: I was thinking about Trim() but I found this solution not usefull too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS 2010 configuration transformation produces unwanted white space during deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300210/vs-2010-configuration-transformation-produces-unwanted-white-space-during-deploy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try installing VS2010 SP1?

Check this: [Web.config transform writes extra line break/spaces to values elements under applicationSettings section](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544183/web-config-transform-writes-extra-line-break-spaces-to-values-elements-under-applicationsettings-section)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about new line, but another solution can be using of custom ConfigSections in web.config and write your URL as attribute value